# FTP удаление выбранных файлов

Tags: php, html

проблема в том, что происходит удаление всех файлов, независимо, от того какие файлы выбраны, не могу понять, в чем проблема.
Буду очень рад помощи.

Вывод названия файлов, которые хранятся на фтп с чекбоксом

```
echo "<form action='php/delete.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
 $cont = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '/');
     for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($cont) ; $i++)
        echo "<br/>" . substr($cont[$i],1) ,
           "<input type='checkbox' name='$i' />" ;

echo "<br/>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Удалить'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Процесс удаления файлов из фтп

```
$images = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '/');
$r = count($images);

for ($i = 0; $i < $r; $i++)
{
    if ($selected_checkbox == $_POST['$i']) {
    $myFile = "$images[$i]";

        if (ftp_delete($conn_id, $myFile)) {
            echo "<br/>";
         echo "Файл $myFile удален \n";
            } else {
                echo "Не удалось удалить $myFile \n";
                }
    }}
```

Comment: Совет на будущее: никогда не пытайтесь делать два дела сразу. У вас тут две задачи: 1. получить информацию из HTML формы. 2. На оснвоании этой информации удалить файлы с фтп. Поскольку у вас серьезные проблемы с рещением первой, её надо сначала решить отдельно, добиться, чтобы код выводил корректный список предназначенных для удаления файлов, а только потом переходить к решению задачи 2.

Comment: И в дополнение. Вы уверены, что массив `$cont` в момент запроса страницы и массив `$images` в момент отправки запроса на удаление совпадают? А что если за время пока думал пользователь, кто-то уже удалил первый файл?